# .Net MySql User Defined Variable as Output Parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I've been searching for a while but the answers I find usually involve stored procedures or different functionality.

I am trying to execute a reader and also return a scalar in the one query.  I thought I could do this using an output parameter, but I get an exception to check my syntax near NULL = @rows_found(), so it appears the output parameter is not getting initialized.

Basically I need to know if this is possible as I haven't found a code sample like this that works.

```
command.CommandText = @"
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        accounting.*
    FROM
        accounting
    WHERE
        transaction_type = @transaction_type
    LIMIT
        @index, @results;

    SET @total_rows = FOUND_ROWS();
";

 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("transaction_type", transaction_type);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("index", index);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("results", results);

 MySqlParameter totalRows = new MySqlParameter("total_rows", 0);
 totalRows.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
 command.Parameters.Add(totalRows);

 using (MySqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
 {
     while (dr.Read())
         invoices.Add(new AccountingDataModel(dr));
 }

 invoices.Total = (int)totalRows.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters["@output"].Value.ToString()
```

Use command object to access your out parameter ....
you can not access out perameter directly.

You Should use like

```
invoices.Total = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["total_rows"].Value.ToString())
```

example for stored procedure

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(nameOfStoredRoutine, connection);    
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    

//input parameters

 for (int i = 0; i < (parameterValue.Length / 2); i++)
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterValue[i, 0], parameterValue[i, 1]);
     cmd.Parameters[parameterValue[i, 0]].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
     parameterList = parameterList + parameterValue[i,0] + " " + parameterValue[i,1] + " ";
  }

  //single output parameter
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@output", MySqlDbType.Int32);
  cmd.Parameters["@output"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Execute command


  return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@output"].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Its actually not getting that far.  From what i read the output parameters are bound when the datareader is closed and this is where the exception is occuring.  Once again, the answer you provide is with a stored procedure.  Im suspecting you cannot use output parameters without a stored procedure, but havent been able to confirm this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not possible. From the documentation of [`MySqlParameter`'s members](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlparametermembers.html) for the `Direction` property:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the parameter is input-only, output-only, bidirectional, or a stored procedure return value parameter. As of MySQL version 4.1 and earlier, input-only is the only valid choice.

So the parameter is, no matter what you set `Direction` to, always an input parameter. If you change the value from `null` to anything else (e.g. 15) you should see that the generated query is something like

```
SET 15 = FOUND_ROWS()
```

Eventually i ended up running two queries. Probably this is not as performant as it could be, but at least it gets the desired result (using EF Core):

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    var estates = context.MySet
        .FromSql("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM myset LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25")
        .ToList();

    var cmd = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";

    var rows = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    context.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```